# Matching cells that contain hexadecimal range

Tags: sql, postgresql, hex

I am trying to query for all rows where column 1 contains a string of pretty much random elements. However, last two-three elements of the string are a hexadecimal value or a decimal (0-255), like:

```
               Column 1              | Column 2
00000587-8bb4-4360-9b0b-79012c14aa6d |  1
00000541-1895-4b13-9de2-7be77dda5de6 |  2
000005db-da97-483d-9efb-69222bbc7b57 |  3
```

I need to get the rows where column 1 contains a string which ends with hexadecimal values ranging from e6 to f2 OR 0-255

Normally would just use something like `where acc.accountid ilike '%e6'` and repeat it for all values in the range but there has to be a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

The hardcore way would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE ('x' || substring (col1 FROM length(col1) - 1))::bit(8)::integer
   BETWEEN 50 AND 200
```

Comment: Thanks. A couple of follow up questions... this is assuming that the length of the strings in column 1 doesn't change and does this cover decimals as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can match the following list of values:

```
field IN ('e6', 'e7', 'e8', 'e9', 'ea', 'eb', 'ec', 'ef', 'eg', 'f0', 'f1', 'f2')
```

Regards.